socket programing problem in header file addition in vs code
I want to start socket programing, but I am using VS code. But I am unable to add the header files of sockets, like I am unable to get the header files like sys/socket.h.. kindly help me.
I tried but unable to find proper solution, I am a beginner in the socket programing currently now.
